# Heater: High temperature only on high speed

Tags: heater

I'm driving an Opel Corsa-C.

Some weeks ago the heater stopped working properly. When I turn it on now, I get warm air for less than a minute. After that it's getting cold again.

When I'm driving faster than 140 km/h it's getting warm again.

What parts can I check to fix this?

Any filters or fuses?

Comment: Due you see any changes in the temperature gauge while this is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your heater, like most cars, works from the heater core. It sounds like your thermostat is opening up if you can get air for a minute, but it goes back off. The thermostat may be closing again, or there me be a blockage in the heater core.

If you're wanting to try replacing parts, I would start with the thermostat first. They're usually pretty cheap, and most people can even put them in themselves. Heater cores, on the other hand, can be a pain to deal with. Most of them are under the dash, and can only be taken out by taking parts of the dash out.

Also, what's the temperatures like there? Has antifreeze been put into the car? List more symptoms and details in your question if you can think of any.

Comment: Seconded for the termostat. I've had to replace mine twice, and it's only about $10. The only caveat is that you may have to drain the antifreeze first, depending on where it is in the line. At the top, you'll be fine, further down, there'll be trouble.

Comment: Finally it was a hose which was nibbled by a marter -.-' => Broken hose => No Antifreeze => No heat -.-'